# Crash on device during language change in cocos2dJs cross platform game (in Android Platform)

Tags: javascript, java, android, game-engine, cocos2d-js

We are getting a crash whenever user changes device language & if game is in background. we are using cocos2dJs3.17.1 to build our games. It seems it is framework issue because to test this scenario we created new blank project & tried the same thing, it crashed.

Steps to produce the crash :

1. Open the game.
2. Go to device settings & change the language.
3. Open the background game (that is there in background )
4. Click some buttons in game ( you should have some button that have some touch events )

game will crash once you click any button.

Stack trace from adb logcat:

```
01-31 12:10:57.814  6212  6451 W cr_ChildProcessConn: onServiceDisconnected (crash or killed by oom): pid=6454
01-31 12:10:57.998  6212  6212 E chromium: [ERROR:aw_browser_terminator.cc(125)] Renderer process (6454) crash detected (code -1).
01-31 12:10:58.026  6212  6212 E chromium: [ERROR:aw_browser_terminator.cc(90)] Render process (6454) kill (OOM or update) wasn't handed by all associated webviews, killing application.
01-31 12:10:58.183  3544  3544 I Zygote  : Process 6212 exited due to signal (9)
01-31 12:10:58.201  3926  4301 I ActivityManager: Process com.x.x (pid 6212) has died: cch+1CAC (117,340)"
```

Any idea or solution please do share in this thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to manually restart the app in those cases.
You can change the main activity slightly as follows:

```
private final String TRIGGER_REBIRTH = "trigger_rebirth";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  if (savedInstanceState != null) {
     if (savedInstanceState.getBoolean(TRIGGER_REBIRTH, false)) {
        // Trigger app restart here
        // See Implementation - https://github.com/JakeWharton/ProcessPhoenix
        ProcessPhoenix.triggerRebirth(this, getIntent());
     }
  }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
  outState.putBoolean(TRIGGER_REBIRTH, true);
}
```

Also prevents the Cocos2d-x JS engine crash, JS_AbortIfWrongThread which happens after user navigates to app which was killed by android while in background.